# Creating if + & statement

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I'm using R and need to create code that checks if a matrix dimensions has 3x3. I am stuck on the proper code using `if()` to check the `nrow` and `ncol`. Any help or suggestion greatly appreciated.

```
localSmoother <- function(myMatrix = matrix(), 
  smoothingMatrix = matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)) 
{ 
  if(class(smoothingMatrix) != "matrix") stop ("smoothingMatrix must be a matrix.")  
  if(ncol(smoothingMatrix) != "3" & if(nrow(smoothingMatrix) != "3") 
  stop ("smoothingMatrix must have dimensions of 3x3") 

  print(myMatrix) # see what myMatrix is.
  print(smoothingMatrix) # see what smoothingMatrix is.
  return(matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
}

# # TEST the CODE:
localSmoother(myMatrix = diag(x = 2, nrow = 5, ncol = 5), smoothingMatrix = matrix(2, nrow = 5, ncol = 3))

# # Error in localSmoother(myMatrix = diag(x = 2, nrow = 5, ncol = 5), smoothingMatrix = matrix(2,  : 

# # smoothingMatrix must be 3x3
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `if(x & if(y)`; instead `if(x & y)`. Also, your liberal use of newlines and lack of `{}` in, for example `if(){}`, looks dangerous...

Comment: `stopifnot(all(dim(x) == 3))`

Answer (score 2):

Most immediately, you have two `if` in your conditional. You should just have one.

```
if(ncol(smoothingMatrix) != "3" & if(nrow(smoothingMatrix) != "3")
## should be
if(ncol(smoothingMatrix) != "3" & nrow(smoothingMatrix) != "3")
```

Next, your logic asks when the number of rows is not 3 *and* the number of columns is not 3. This condition works as intended (returns TRUE and follows to the stop statement in the `if` block) if your dimension is `c(5,4)`, but would fail if your dimension is `c(5,3)`.

```
x <- matrix(1:20,nrow=5)
dim(x)
# [1] 5 4
ncol(x) != "3" & nrow(x) != "3" 
# [1] TRUE

x <- matrix(1:12,nrow=3)
dim(x)
# [1] 3 4
ncol(x) != "3" & nrow(x) != "3" 
# [1] FALSE
```

I would instead use either of the following equivalent lines:

```
if(!(ncol(smoothingMatrix) == 3 && nrow(smoothingMatrix) == 3))
## is the same as
if(ncol(smoothingMatrix) != 3 || nrow(smoothingMatrix) != 3)
```

Note two things:

1. I'm using the logical operators `&&` and `||` instead of the vectorized operators `&` and `|`. Try `c(TRUE, FALSE) & TRUE` vs. `c(TRUE, FALSE) && TRUE`.
2. I am using the numeric form `3` instead of the character `"3"`. R will coerce the number to a character, so the equality test works here, but it could trip you up in other cases.

It may be easier to compare on the dimension of the matrix:

```
if(!isTRUE(all.equal(dim(smoothingMatrix),c(3L,3L))))
```

(`isTRUE` is needed because `all.equal` returns either `TRUE` or a character vector describing the differences. Observe that `all.equal(1,0)` does not return `FALSE` but instead a character vector describing the differences. Any `if` statements around `all.equal` then throw an error if equality doesn't hold.)

```
all.equal(1,0)
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 1"

if(all.equal(1,0)) print(TRUE) 
# Error in if (all.equal(1, 0)) print(TRUE) : 
#   argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your points 1 and 2. Both things around `&&` are scalars in the example, right? And `ncol()` returns an integer, not a character, so I guess there might be some conversion of the integer to numeric when using `==`...? Also, could you explain the use of `isTRUE` at the end? Is that protecting against `dim` returning `NA`s?

Comment: Holy cow, that's several tips for my mind to wrap around. Thanks @Blue Magister and Frank for the new ideas and more efficient concepts!

Comment: @Frank Points 1 and 2 are not core to the logic error of the `if` statement, but are good general programming practices in R. If you expect a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, use logical operators `&&` and `||`. If you expect a number, use comparison with numbers (quickly with `==`; preferably with `all.equal`). I've added some info on `isTRUE` to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Blue Magister's answer is great with nice explanations, go there first.

For your specific task, you might find the `stopifnot` function useful. From `?stopifnot`

> `stopifnot(...)` If any of the expressions in ... are not all TRUE, stop is called, producing an error message indicating the first of the elements of ... which were not true.

Your code could then be

```
stopifnot(is.matrix(smoothingMatrix),
          ncol(smoothingMatrix) == 3,
          nrow(smoothingMatrix) == 3)
```

The downside is that the error messages are a bit less helpful, the upside is that you don't have to write them yourself, and the code is nice and clean.